# Lifetime of EWS Managed API streamingsubscription

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I have a streaming subscription that is set to 30 minutes. The `ondisconnect` event is wired to reconnect.

However there is a small gap of sometimes 300 ms between disconnect until connected again.

Will I have to write some code myself to handle if a mail arrives in this small gap, or is the event fired again upon connection?

Answer (score 0):

I once tested this case against an on-premise Exchange 2010, and the events fall in the small gap CAN fire once we reopen the streaming connection (which holds the old subscription Id of course).

So no need to write own code to handle the small gap.
BTW, I even tested "small gap" of longer than 2 minutes, and Exchange still can cache the changes and fire them on reconnect.